# PyCharm - Expected type 'Optional[IO[str]]', got 'TextIOWrapper[str]' instead

Tags: python

After updating PyCharm to 2017.1, a new inspection warning started to pop up in a place where everything's seemingly simple and correct. It looks as following:

[image: Screenshot]

It looks like `open()` doesn't return the expected type for `file` parameter, but the code is pretty straightforward and, most importantly, does work as expected (using Python 3.5.2).

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) mention a way using `StringIO` and it removes the warning indeed, *but* is it the correct pythonic way to specify output stream for `print`? If so, why? Is this warning important to follow?

Comment: It's a known issue [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23288)

Answer (score 8):

The only solution I found is to type hint PyCharm correctly:

```
from typing import IO

with open('output_filename', 'w') as f:  # type: IO[str]
    print('some text to go to the file...', file=f)
```

This keeps PyCharm happy and does not in any way impede the correct running of your code.

Comment: Wouldn't `type: IO[str]` make more sense? Still silences the PyCharm warning.

Comment: Isn't the type returned from open is file? Better disable python type check and add a comment in the code with a link to the youtrack:         # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        # pycharm complains that f is not of type file but this is a known bug:
        # https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23288